# How to generate HTML without the MVC classes?

Tags: joomla-3.x

I found nothing related to non-MVC component creation in the Joomla docs. Maybe the problem is with me or with my search keywords. Anyways, I am curious whether there is a templating engine I can use, or should I just use plain PHP + HTML, and the CSS will cover the rest? I guess Joomla will fill my content into the content area of the page. Any best practices?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? Unless I've misunderstood your question, you might be able to create such a beast by adding HTML and javascript to the article page (or module), styling it with CSS and adding PHP with an extension such as RegularLabs' Sourcerer component. Best practices would be to not do it as I described, but to instead use MVC.

Comment: @oooooo Nope, I just want to integrate my app with Joomla without using the MVC classes and library structure available by extensions. I simply don't like it. That's all. I don't want Sourcerer either because of security reasons. Most of the app is complete now, all I need is the presentation part, so routing, copying some validation from the model and generating a gui. I am looking for Joomla helper classes I could use to do this stuff, so I don't have to reinvent the wheel. E.g. I liked JUserHelper by adding new users and groups to the system from my extension.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was too superficial by reading the docs. There are many classes I can possibly reuse by writing the code of my presentation layer.

It is possible to access the current router with `$japp->getRouter()`, so in theory it is possible to add customer routes and call the `execute($route)` after that. By routing you can use the `JApplicationWebRouter` abstract class or its descendants `JApplicationWebRouterBase` or `JApplicationWebRouterRest`. The `JApplicationWebRouter` can be okay. You must implement the `parseRouter(string $route) -> string $controllerName` and that's all. If you accept that you use only `JController` implementations and these implementations are instantiated by the router the following way `new JControllerImpl($japp, $jinput)` then it is fully reusable. Sadly this is not acceptable to me. The controllers are instantiated by a di container in my case, so I have to write my own router. The controller instantiation should have been put into a separate abstract method in this `JApplicationWebRouter` class. I am not sure whether it is mandatory to have at least one `JController` implementation in the component. In normal libs the site and admin entries; `example.php`, `admin/example.php` would contain some middleware installation code, which register the controllers on the router as well and the registered controllers would handle the requests. The docs and examples are chaotic regarding to this, but I guess you can handle requests in these entry points if you don't have a controller.php file, which I feel strange.

By validation and type conversion I can use the `JInput` class. I will use `$jinput->getString($name, $default)` and `$jinput->getInt($name, $default)` most of the time.

By json response I can use the `JResponseJson`, but I don't like the json envelope it uses. The devs probably never heard of HTTP status headers, that's why they put things like `succcess:true` into the json. An alternative approach to set the mime type with `JFactory::getDocument()->setMimeEncoding($mimeType)`. Be aware that this should contain only the mime type and subtype, so this is not a content-type header with charset. According to the docs you'll need a `Content-Disposition` header too, they never explained why. As far as I remember I never used that by my single page javascript applications. I would be more worried about xhr response caching and things like that, but I did not find any cache support in `JDocument` or `JApplication` or `JResponseJson`, so I assume it is non-existent and in the best scenario it is set to `private`, `no-cache`. I did not expect content security policy and cors support after this.

By rendering HTML it is possible to reuse `JLayout` implementations `JLayoutBase` and its descendant `JLayoutFile`. The `JLayoutBase` doesn't give you much. The `JLayoutFile` contains the important part; template file loading, compile and evaluation. By instantiation you need to use `new JLayoutFile($layoutId, $basePath, $options)`, so for example: `$layout = new JLayoutFile('joomla.content.tags', JPATH_SITE . '/components/com_mycomponent/layouts')` will load `/components/com_mycomponent/layouts/joomla/content/tags.php` if I understand well. Afaik. this solution is somewhat similar to adding a directory to the path and trying to find the layout file using all of the path directories. So it will use the template dir `templates/mytemplate/html/layouts` too, not just the component dir. It is okay, I mean I might be able to reuse some of the template layouts. For example I need to display input fields and their labels somehow in a multi column layout. It is possible to instantiate and render `JLayoutFile` with `JLayoutHelper` too. Actually I'll add a method to one of my containers to do that, so the base dir will be automatically injected. I'll probably won't use nested directory structures so I won't need the dot separation I used in this example.

It is possible to insert css and js code to the HTML using the `JDocument`. Afaik. these files must be in the media folder.

I can use `JForm` to construct and validate forms. According to the docs it uses XML to describe the form. I am reading about this currently.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing in the doc and no best practice for not following MVC.  On the other hand Joomla will let you do whatever you want without complaint.  It will execute your entry files and then you can do anything you want - such as loading a templating engine, making your own routing processes, etc.  But once you leave behind MVC you kind of have to make your own way.

Comment: This is not entirely true. I just found a lot of classes I could reuse from the joomla lib. I'll check them later and write an answer.